# View alternate windows registry using java

Tags: java, windows, registry

I have JUnits (32 bit application) to which I want to expose 64 bit windows registries on my 64-bit windows OS.

I read that using the windows flag 'KEY_WOW64_64KEY' I can turn on 64-bit view.

Where in the registry do I go and set this flag?

But how do I do that easily in Java? Is there a way which avoids JNI and any reference to advapi32.dll?